# Store and resue password in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to store a password using python and then re-use it .  I want to store a password using python and then re-use it . How can I do this in a secured way ?

Comment: Why do you copy your first sentence verbatim in the second? :)

Answer (score 0):

Searching around I found this: [PassLib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). You can pip install it

```
pip install passlib
```

And then use it. This is from the example in their link.

```
>>> # import the hash algorithm
>>> from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

>>> # generate new salt, and hash a password
>>> hash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash("toomanysecrets")
>>> hash
'$pbkdf2-sha256$29000$N2YMIWQsBWBMae09x1jrPQ$1t8iyB2A.WF/Z5JZv.lfCIhXXN33N23OSgQYThBYRfk'

>>> # verifying the password
>>> pbkdf2_sha256.verify("toomanysecrets", hash)
True
>>> pbkdf2_sha256.verify("joshua", hash)
False
```